# How to "nest" an MVC Core application inside an existing MVC Core site

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking at building a "dashboard" of sorts used when developing/debugging an ASPNET MVC Core site. The tricky part is that I would like my own dashboard to itself be an MVC Core site and I do not want it to interfere with the "parent" site.

Ideally, the wireup would be as simple as:

```
app.UseMyDashboard("/somepath");
```

This would then expose my own MVC Core application at this path. Complete with it's own service container so as not to pollute the parent site with any of the services required to run the dashboard application.

If it all possible I would like it to be entirely self contained.

Comment: Hi, I think you've answered your own question.  What you suggest  sounds perfectly OK.  Give it a try and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Monza - unfortunately it doesn't. The two versions of MVC clash, if you have controllers named the same thing MVC get's confused and isn't sure which ones to use, the route tables get mingled together, etc.

Comment: An "area" is a little carve-out within your app that can operate independently.  If that doesn't work you should host your MVC and MVC Core adjacent to one another an enable CORS so that they can talk to one another.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - they share the same MVC Options, they share the same `ServiceProvider`. They aren't independent. An area is really just a grouping of routes.

Answer (score 1):

That's not usually on how you do it. The normal case in modular/microservice Applications is to create separate applications which run on their own port and use a reverse proxy (nginx, IIS) to to route it to the correct application.

But you can also use `UseWhen` for branching.

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWith("dashboard"), appBuilder =>
{
    // register here branched middlewares etc. 
}
```

But that's not exactly what you asked for though

Comment: That requires significant setup for the consuming party. Think of a situation like http://hangfire.io/ where they embed their own dashboard (by the looks of things, by bringing over their own razor implementation bits). Ideally we'd have absolutely minimal impact on the consuming code.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [.NET MVC Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas)

According to the MSDN documentation: "An area is effectively an MVC structure inside an application"

This allows you to have a totally separate routing scheme and parallel structure for your internal needs. You could have everything the same except an area prefix.

Comment: Area's isn't really what I want as they are not entirely self contained. They use the same `ServiceProvider` as the "primary" app, etc.